# Adding a column of numbers as a first column to an already existing TEXT file with numbers using PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text-files

I am trying to add a column of increasing multiples of 4,say (4 8 12 16)  to an already existing data of numbers of a TEXT file. However, when I try the code [mentioned below] the column data is adding at the end of the data of the existing text file. I cannot use PANDAS because Abaqus software do not have it.

Here is the Existing data in a text file sample example, (i used  comma here to separate the integers):

53   ,    25

55   ,   39

78   ,   87

32   ,   17

Expected output:

4  , 53 ,  25

8 , 55  , 39

12 ,78  , 87

16 ,32 ,  17

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np

# defining the numbers i want to add to the text file

x1 = np.array(range(4,20,4)).tolist()

# opening the existing data file using **append** format

exisiting_data = open('data.txt', 'a')

# looping through the numbers to add to the text file

for eachitem in x1:

    exisiting_data.write(str(eachitem)+'\n')

exisiting_data.close()
```

output:
When i do this I am getting the output as

53   ,    25

55   ,   39

78   ,   87

32   ,   17

4

8

12

16

I think this is simple for many of you. I am a beginner for now. Thank you for your suggestions and answers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly write your series as the first column in your text file. What you can do is that you can create a second file and write your series(4, 8, 12) + data from your first file to the second one.

Comment: existing_ data_file = open("data.txt" , "r")  .............




numbers_file = open("numbers.txt" , "w").............



for line in existing_ data_file:
    
    
    numbers_file.write(line)

Comment: I tried your suggestions and written this code. But unfortunately data in the second file is getting erased because of the 'w' format. Kindly help me writing a code in your mind. Please

Comment: I think you can try this
`with open("two.txt", "w") as f:
    lines = open("one.txt").readlines()
    x = 4
    for line in lines:
        f.write(str(x) + "," + line)
`